# rust: How do roolback BytesMut

Tags: rust

```
let mut buf = BytesMut::with_capacity(1024);
buf.put_u64(100);

buf.get_u64();
//rollback
buf.get_u64();
```

I used BytesMut.
sometimes, I want rollback BytesMut pos,and next repeat call 'buf.get_u64()',
how do?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. In particular there is no `BytesMut` in the standard library, so we need to know where `BytesMut` comes from.

Comment: BytesMut   from.  bytes="1.1.0"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't since the operation of reading from `BytesMut` shrinks the buffer.  It only* retains a pointer to the start of the buffer and the buffer length. Since it is unable to know how far it has progressed while reading, it instead is forced to shift the start pointer up with each read. However, you can wrap the underlying data with a [`std::io::Seek`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Seek.html) type such as [`Cursor`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Cursor.html) to store the position within the buffer separately. A `Cursor` manages the position for you as data is read from the buffer, but still gives you the option to move the cursor wherever you would like.

```rust
use bytes::{Buf, BufMut, BytesMut};
use std::io::{Cursor, Seek, SeekFrom};
use std::mem::size_of;

let mut buffer = BytesMut::with_capacity(1024);
buffer.put_u64(5678);

// Create cursor so we can move position in data
let mut cursor: Cursor<&[u8]> = Cursor::new(&*buffer);

let a = cursor.get_u64();

// Rollback buffer position by the size of a u64 (always 8, but use mem::size_of
// to make intentions clearer)
cursor
    .seek(SeekFrom::Current(-(size_of::<u64>() as i64)))
    .expect("Exceeded limits of buffer");

// The next value we get should now be the same as the previous
let b = cursor.get_u64();
assert_eq!(a, b);
```

Comment: @ChayimFriedman I added the asterisk since I was describing a simplified interpretation where there are some caveats to my explanation. In actuality `BytesMut` also contains a capacity and an atomic reference counter so it can maintain shared ownership of the underlying buffer. 'only' might not have been the best word choice, but my point was more that there is no cursor stored in `BytesMut` which can be moved back.